# Can not access via ssh and view layout without css

Tags: git, gitlab

I set up the Gitlab in my company LAN,

Now, I can access the Gitlab server by

`http://dqa-test`

But when I ran `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production`

I got `Check GitLab API access: FAILED. code: 404`

```
I've change the `host:` with dqa-test, dqa-test/ , with `http://` or not
```

But after all the above tries, it still got the same error by running self-check

I can clone a project from via http , but no way in `ssh`

```
git clone git@dqa-test:vvtk_dqa_automation_team/sandbox.git
Cloning into 'sandbox'...
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My gitlab.yml

```
  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings (note: host is the FQDN, do not include http://)
    host: "http://dqa-test"
    port: 1987
    https: false
```

I have no idea why I don't have the correct layout

It doesn't work when I ran `sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production`

I found the source code of html page are weird , but have no idea

The link should not start with double slashes

```
<link href="//assets/favicon-220424ba6cb497309f8faf8545eb5408.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
<link href="//assets/application-1266844103d9cc711308315f1502e346.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//assets/application-1a2e2b81d35aebc17df9d360d291a8b1.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you generate a key pair and provide the public key to gitlab?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the layout problem is concerned with gitlab CSS and assets not showing. I had the same issue upgrading from gitlab 6.6 to 7.14 (Cent OS 6.7) following these instructions:

https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/update/6.x-or-7.x-to-7.14.md

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#using-https

1) Permissions issue despite following the above instructions, so I had to manually change ownership of the assets folder to allow the cache to clear and then have the assets precompile and write to that dir:

In `/home/git/gitlab/`

`sudo chmod -R u+rwX public`

`chown -R --reference favicon.ico assets`

Then this works without write errors:

`sudo -u git -H bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile cache:clear RAILS_ENV=production`

2) However that did not fix the look of my Gitlab install this did:

`nano /home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml`

Uncomment out the line:

> default_theme: 2 # default: 2

If you don't have a theme - weird things will happen!